# jQuery animate width to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to animate div to slide to the right like the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/56hxy/3/

but instead of shifting the margin, I want to "squish" the width but it's not working by changing the width %  ( `width: '60%'` )  it squishes to the left instead..

Comment: Please clarify. Preferably with images. a link to fiddle would become useless once it's removed/changed

Comment: Which width do you want to squish?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but try:

```
$('#content').animate({
    marginLeft: '40%',
    width:'60%'
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/56hxy/4/)

---

Or give `right:0` to `#content` in the CSS, then you can animate the `width` and it will shrink from left to right without requiring margins. Same effect as the above but cleaner. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/56hxy/8/)

Also, jQuery has a built-in "[toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)" for alternating clicks so, if you're toggling just the click event you can use:

```
$('#content').toggle(function() { 
    $(this).animate({ width:'60%' }); 
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ width:'100%' }); 
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/56hxy/12/)

Comment: hmm, that toggle event is awesome. If I toggle the same targeted element (the animated elem) with another toggle event attached elsewhere, will the toggle event associated to '#content' recognize that the targeted element has already been toggled?

Comment: Eh I guess not. Toggle is very limited. I'm pretty sure it just toggles when fired from the same handler. You could, theoretically, `.trigger('click')` on the element which has a toggle event associated with and it'd work then. Toggle is mostly for simple stuff though, if you need a robust solution, keep your manual toggling. `=]`

Comment: @bushdiver This is an example of what I meant in the last comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XVZRc/ - you can see, it gets a little more complicated so keeping a flag as you did initially is probably more concise then.